# Angular js how to use scope data in a scope array. The proper way

Tags: angularjs, scope, angular-ngmodel

I'm facing some kind of trouble. How can I do this?

```
$scope.data = {
   a: $scope.a,
   b: $scope.b
}
```

I got undefined. I need those scopes in the data scope.

Comment: Is `$scpoe` a typo in your question or is that in your code?

Comment: Its a typo sorry, any ideas?

Comment: Can you include more code that shows how your other scope variables are defined?

Comment: Its just an example. Is it possible to use many scopes as a scope array data?

Comment: Okay !right now im using my phone

Comment: You can define it in that way so if you're getting undefined, then you must be referencing an undefined variable. Are you sure it's the same scope, ie not a isolate scope?

Comment: Actualy scope.a and scope.b coe after scope.data {}. So i've used the rootscope. Ex :rootscope.a

Comment: Thank you Tristan. You were right. I had the scope.a in a if statement. Its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi u can do like that can store a scope inside in your data object check this

**[image: JS]**

```
$scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.name2 = 'World';
  $scope.data = {
   a:  $scope.name,
   b: $scope.name2
}
console.log($scope.data)
console.log($scope.data.a)
console.log($scope.data.b)
```